# Javascript WebSocket устанавливает соединение единожды или при каждой отправке сообщения?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Есть Javascript сокет:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://site.com/demo");
ws.onopen = function() { ... };
ws.onclose = function() { ... };
ws.onmessage = function(evt) { ... };
```

И есть один простой вопрос. Соединение с веб-сервером устанавливается каждый раз при отправке каждого любого сообщения

```
ws.send(...);
```

или же всего один раз? Насколько мне известно, отправив с помощью такого сокета сообщение, на веб-сервер поступает GET-запрос. Но он поступает по изначально установленному соединению **или** создаётся новое соединение с веб-сервером?

Comment: Никаких GET-запросов при отправке сообщения не отправляется, соединение устанавливается единожды и держится до закрытия вебсокета

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все сообщения в обе стороны отправляются по одному соединению, в этом весь смысл WebSockets.

> Насколько мне известно, отправив с помощью такого сокета сообщение, на веб-сервер поступает GET-запрос.

Это не так, на самом деле. Сокеты работают по [собственному протоколу](http://learn.javascript.ru/websockets#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0), а не по HTTP, поэтому типов запросов из HTTP у них нет. Но сокеты реализованы поверх HTTP, поэтому при установке соединения действительно отправляется GET-запрос. Но дальше уже никакой семантики HTTP нет.

Comment: Если я в этот веб-сокет буду слать предложения, разделённые символом новой строки \n, то каждое такое предложение я смогу получать отдельно в этом коде: `ws.onmessage = function(evt) { \* получить предложение*\ };`, верно? Или как-то по-другому сообщения разделяются?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю при чём тут символ новой строки, но да - на каждое отправленное сообщение колбек сработает отдельно.

Comment: @LEsperanza Символ новой строки тут ни при чём, сколько раз send вызовите - столько сообщений и получите

Comment: @andreymal, а возможно ли сделать так, чтобы сообщения сокет мог принимать не зависимо от того, сколько раз метод `ws.send(...);` был вызван?

Comment: Так и делается - никакого лимита на количество сообщений нет. Если вы хотите отправлять одно сообщение частями, а на клиенте работать с ним как с целым, то вам нужно сделать всю эту логику самостоятельно, WebSockets - низкоуровневый протокол. Обойти логику одно сообщение - один вызов колбэка не получится, но внутри колбека вы можете собирать какую-то свою структуру и выполнять какую-то логику, когда всё будет готово.
Лучше опишите свою проблему подробно в отдельном вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

```
// соеденение с веб-сокетом здесь происходит, причём один раз
ws = new WebSocket("ws://site.com/demo");  

// это обработчик, который срабатывает сразу же при успешном подключении
ws.onopen = function() { ... }; 

// этот при закрытии соответственно
ws.onclose = function() { ... };

// а этот всякий раз при получении ответа от сервера
ws.onmessage = function(evt) { ... };
```